# Rewrite for loop that is slowing down in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a for loop that is slowing down as it is processing a list of raster files (same operation on every file in the list). The initial items in the list are processed in a second or two, while toward the end of the 220 item list, time is ~ 30 seconds. Once the script exits the for loop and starts another list of files, it resets and the initial processing takes a second or two. So I think the issue is the loop itself.

Here is pseudo code as to what I have:

```
files = ['file1.tif', 'file2.tif', . . . ,'file222.tif']

for file in files:
    start_time = time.time()
    process file here
    outfile.save('out.tif')
    del all processing files
    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
    gc.collect()
```

I just can't understand why it is slowing down so much, and am wondering if there is a better way to write this loop.

Comment: You could try asyncio. If disk IO operations are the bottleneck it will allow you to process the next file already

Comment: I can look into that, but if disk IO operations are a bottleneck, wouldn't that show up in the initial parts of the loop?

Comment: idk if it is buffered somewhere your buffer might get full. What do you do with the processing? An easy way to check is to run you loop threaded (so that you dont have to rewrite everything be async). Also did you do any benchmarking which step takes up the most time?

Comment: I didn't benchmark the individual steps, only the loop. The processing output is written to a file and "presumably" nothing should be carried over in memory. Clearly something is, but I am not sure how to identify where this is occurring. I guess I will have to look at the individual commands in the loop.

Comment: Yes that would be helpful, I am sorry but i cannot reproduce your issue with the info here. Let me know if you are still stuck after benchmarking